# Percentage axis only in positive range

Tags: chart.js, axis, percentage

How can I limit the percentage scale to the positive range of the first Y-axis? The crossed out curve should only be displayed in the positive area as shown.

[image]

My current configuration of the Y axes:

```
   y: {
        type: 'linear', 
        position: 'left',
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
           stepSize: 1000,
           font: {
             size: 20,
           }
        }
      },
    
      y2: {
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'right',
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        grid: {
            drawOnChartArea: false
        },
        ticks: {
           stepSize: 20,
           font: {
             size: 20,
           },
           callback: function(value, index, values) {
              return value + ` %`;
           }
        }
      },

    }
```

Comment: You have to compute the scaling of the `y2` axis, such that the zeros match and the max of `y2` is `100`. With the data in the image, if you set for `y2`, `min: -100`, `max: 100`, and in the `callback` `return value >= 0 ? value+' %' : '';` you'll get close to what you want. For a concrete answer, please provide the required [minimal  reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that is an example that can be run, full with data, but not necessarily all 10 curves.

Comment: Hi @kikon, the hint is great, it works like I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
y2: {
        type: 'linear',
        display: 'auto',
        position: 'right',
        min: -100,
        max: 100,
        grid: {
            drawOnChartArea: false
        },
        ticks: {
           stepSize: 20,
           font: {
             size: 20,
           },
           callback: function(value, index, values) {
              return value >= 0 ? value + ' %' : '';
           }
        }
      },
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the code here, taken from my comment to OP **was not intended as a full solution**, but just an initial step, that was only supposed to work approximately in a specific case;  it was clearly described as such. More precisely, this only works if the `min` and `max` of the `y` axis are equal in absolute value. Otherwise, the zeros of the two axes are not at the same position, unless a formula is used to compute the `min` for `y2`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint,
The following code should fit better.

```
y2: {
  type: 'linear',
  display: 'auto',
  position: 'right',
  min: (context) => {
      return (context.chart.scales.y.min / context.chart.scales.y.max * 100)
  },
  max: 100,
  grid: {
      drawOnChartArea: false
  },
  ticks: {
     stepSize: 20,
     font: {
       size: 20,
     },
     callback: function(value, index, values) {
        return value >= 0 ? value + ' %' : '';
     }
  }
},
```

It doesn't always work correctly, if you hide values ​​by clicking on the legend. I do not know why.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**